# testng.xml is not running multiple classes from different packages

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Here are my code snippets:
**BrowserFactory.java** in package A

```
public class Browserfactory {
    public static void startBrowser(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", strFirefoxDriverPath);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(someSampleURL);
    }

    @BeforeTest()
    public void setDriver() {       
        Reports.configAndPrepareReport();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDownDriver() {
        driver.quit();
        Reports.writeToHTML();
    }

    @BeforeSuite
    public void startSuite() {
        BrowserFactory.startBrowser();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void endSuite() {
        Reports.closeTheChannelToHTMLReport();
    }
}
```

**VerifyCheckboxesPage.java** in package B

```
public class VerifyCheckboxesPage extends BrowserFactory{
    CheckboxesPage objCheckboxesPage;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        new MainPage(BrowserFactory.driver).goToCheckboxesPage();
        objCheckboxesPage = new CheckboxesPage(BrowserFactory.driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifyCheckboxesPageHeader() {
        if(objCheckboxesPage.txtHeader.getText().equals("Checkboxes")) {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS);
        }
        else {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.FAIL);
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifyCountOfCheckboxes() {
        if(objCheckboxesPage.chkCheckboxes.size() == 2) {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS);
        }
        else {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.FAIL);
        }
    }
}
```

**CheckboxesPage.java** in package C

```
public class CheckboxesPage{
    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(someMethodToFindObjectsOnPage)
    public WebElement txtHeader;

    @FindAll({@FindBy(someMethodToFindObjects)})
    public List<WebElement> chkCheckboxes;

    public CheckboxesPage(WebDriver driver) {   
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

**VerifyABTestingPage.java** in package B

```
public class VerifyABTestingPage extends BrowserFactory{
    ABTestingPage objABTestingPage;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        Reports.startTest("Verify A/B Testing page");
        new MainPage(BrowserFactory.driver).goToABTestingPage();
        objABTestingPage = new ABTestingPage(BrowserFactory.driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifyABTestingPageHeader() {
        if(objABTestingPage.txtHeader.getText().equals("A/B Test Control")){
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS);
        }
        else {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.FAIL);
        }
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifyABTestingPageBody() {
        if(objABTestingPage.txtBody.getText().contains(strExpectedBody)) {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS);
        }
        else {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.FAIL);
        }
    }
}
```

**ABTestingPage.java** in package C

```
public class ABTestingPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(someMethodToLocateObject)
    public WebElement txtHeader;

    @FindBy(someMethodToLocateObject)
    public WebElement txtBody;

    public ABTestingPage(WebDriver driver) {    
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.java** in package C

```
public class MainPage {
    @FindBy(someMethodToLocateObject)
    public WebElement lnkABTesting;

    @FindBy(someMethodToLocateObject)
    public WebElement lnkCheckboxes;

    WebDriver driver;

    public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    }

    public void goToABTestingPage() {   
        new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(lnkABTesting)).click();
    }

    public void goToCheckboxesPage() {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(lnkCheckboxes)).click();
    }
}
```

**Finally, here is how my testng.xml looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.herokuapp.internet.tests.VerifyCheckboxesPage"/>
      <class name="com.herokuapp.internet.tests.VerifyABTestingPage"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

*Problem statement: When I run my test cases from testng.xml by right clicking on the xml file and clicking on Run As > TestNGSuite, it runs just VerifyCheckboxesPage (the 1st class name in testng xml) and that too only the 1st test case of this class. Not sure why.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out to re-configure testNG.xml   and annotate your tests

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Functional Smoke Jenkins suite" parallel="false" thread-count="5" verbose="8">

<test name="test name FIRST">
    <parameter name="env" value="DEFAULT"/>
    <groups>
        <run>                
            <include name="smoke"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.herokuapp.internet.tests.VerifyCheckboxesPage"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="test name SECOND">
    <parameter name="env" value="DEFAULT"/>
    <groups>
        <run>                
            <include name="smoke"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.herokuapp.internet.tests.VerifyABTestingPage"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

And please annotate  Tests with appropriate group names:

```
  @Test(priority = 1,groups = {"smoke})
    public void verifyABTestingPageHeader() {
        if(objABTestingPage.txtHeader.getText().equals("A/B Test Control")){
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS);
        }
        else {
            Reports.logStatus(LogStatus.FAIL);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps at least in debugging phase. Let me know what results You will get.

**P.s**  please try to follow with Your setup accurately step-by-step from official [testNg doc here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).

Comment: Here's how I modified the xml file:

Comment: @PraveenPandey, please double check why You're getting NPE in VerifyABTestingPage.verifyABTestingPageHeader (to be exact 
 in VerifyABTestingPage.java, string 35) .  You may wrap with try-catch block to analyze full stacktrace and please also you debug and do step-by-step debug.  Obviously You have something not properly initialized.

Comment: Oh yes. I found that the object 'test' was not initialized. It has started working now. Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenPandey , please approve the answer and put upvote if possible :) Thanks